# How to query Yammer?

Tags: search, yammer

I need to query Yammer for Hashtags. For example return me all messages which includes `#Mercedes`. I have looked at the developer portal and found `search.json` => https://developer.yammer.com/docs/searchjson. But when i tried to search for `#Mercedes` it returns everything including `Mercedes` without a Hastag.

Is this possible? How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should query

`https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/:Topic_ID.json`

(https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesabout_topicidjson), where Topic_ID is a numeric ID of the topic which you can get by visiting the topic page in Yammer.

Comment: Ok, but where to get the topic id from? Its only numerical values allowed

Comment: I guess only manually from Yammer website - when you click on a topic in Yammer, you'll see the ID in URL

Comment: On the url you mentioned there is a statement: `Topics, along with their ids, can be retrieved using search or autocomplete.` Do you have any idea how to get only topics from search?

Comment: This works - https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search=%23somegreattopic&model_types=topic